# Trying to use window.history.replaceState() to modify url without redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, window

I'm trying to create an app where, when you logout, you get a url that allows you to redirect back to the page you were just on.  Here is an example:

`http://localhost:8888/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F%23%2FuserProfile/`

I currently have a route defined in my login page where if path === '/' then redirect to '/login'.  So when the url above is created it hits this route and tries to go to:

`http://localhost:8888/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F%23%2FuserProfile/#/login` instead of:

`http://localhost:8888/#/login/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F%23%2FuserProfile/`

I'm trying to fix this using `window.history.replaceState()` but if the replacement url contains `#` it appends it like this:

`http://localhost:8888/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F%23%2FuserProfile/#/login/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F%23%2FuserProfile`

If I don't include the hash it looks correct but the hash is missing (i.e.):

`http://localhost:8888/login/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F%23%2FuserProfile/`

The documentation around this method is poor.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or even if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can replace the entire url or specify a replacement hash.